# Iterate through each item in accordion block with Selenium & Python

Tags: python, selenium, boto

I've got an accordion block which I'd like to click each item & take a screenshot. Each item shares a class so I thought a for loop would work but I can't get it to select the items.

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="accordionContainer">
    <div class="accordion">
      <h3>Click This</h3>
      <div class="accordionContent" style="display:none">
      </div>
    <div>
    <div class="accordion">
      <h3>Click This</h3>
      <div class="accordionContent" style="display:none">
      </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Python:

```
detailsAccordion = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('accordion')
index = 1
for option in detailsAccordion:
    option.click()
    try:
        element = ui.WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordion'][" + str(index) + "]/div[@class='accordionContent']").text != "" )
    except:
        print "Can't do it"
        browser.quit()
    index = index + 1
    n = nextNumber(n)
    browser.save_screenshot('{0}\{1}.png'.format(imagesPath, n))
    option.click()
```

This is causing a timeout with the following error. I've looked at this error & people have had trouble with internet options/proxy settings - I don't have a proxy so no sure why this has started;

```
 [exec] Can't do it
 [exec] Traceback (most recent call last):
 [exec]   File "viewEmployeeUseCase.py", line 82, in <module>
 [exec]     ff.save_screenshot('{0}\{1}.png'.format(imagesPath, n))
 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.20.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 75, in save_screenshot
 [exec]     png = RemoteWebDriver.execute(self, Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']

 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.20.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 151, in execute
 [exec]     response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)

 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.20.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 280, in execute
 [exec]     return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.20.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 321, in _request
 [exec]     response = opener.open(request)
 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
 [exec]     response = self._open(req, data)
 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
 [exec]     '_open', req)
 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
 [exec]     result = func(*args)
 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1170, in http_open
 [exec]     return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
 [exec]   File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1145, in do_open
 [exec]     raise URLError(err)
 [exec] urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

Making things simple & not waiting for content to populate works fine & does all I want it to with the following;

```
for option in detailsAccordion:
    #print option
    option.click()
    WebDriverWait(ff, 2)
    n = nextNumber(n)
    ff.save_screenshot('{0}\{1}.png'.format(imagesPath, n))
    option.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the implicit wait is what you want and I do not believe it is doing anything in your code. "An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance." - [Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits)

What you really want is an [explicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-waits) that waits for the accordian content to appear and then takes the screenshot.

Sorry, not a Python programmer, so I am guessing at the exact code. But I think you want something like:

```
detailsAccordion = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('accordion')
for option in detailsAccordion:
    option.click() # open div
    #Wait until the accordionContent div has text
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda option : option.find_element_by_class_name("accordionContent").text != "" )
    finally:
        #Throw error cause the div didn't populate
        browser.quit
    n = nextNumber(n)
    browser.save_screenshot('{0}\{1}.png'.format(imagesPath, n))
    option.click() #close div
```

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I think there are two major issues with the solution I originally suggested. (1) It should be `except:` instead of `finally:` since `finally:` always executes rather than just if there's a timeout error. (2) Unlike Watir-Webdriver, it seems that Selenium-Webdriver does not allow checking the `accordionContent` with respect to the current `accordion` element. The originally proposed solution is always checking the first `accordionContent` on the page (bad). The only way I could find the element with respect to another element is using xpath (or css-selector).

The following has been updated with these two concepts:

```
detailsAccordion = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('accordion')
index = 1
for option in detailsAccordion:
    print option
    option.click()
    try:
        element = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordion'][" + str(index) + "]/div[@class='accordionContent']").text != "" )
    except:
        # Error if div didn't populate
        print "Can't do it"
        browser.quit()
    index = index + 1
    n = nextNumber(n)
    browser.save_screenshot('{0}\{1}.png'.format(imagesPath, n))
    option.click()
```

Comment: Thank you. I've only been using python & selenium for a few weeks so theres plenty I don't know about! That seems to be more successful but it times out so I think my problem is in the `option.click()` although it is a WebDriver element which does support the click()

Comment: Being a Ruby Watir-Webdriver person, I made some incorrect assumptions. I have updated the suggested script to account for some issues I noticed. See if that helps.

Comment: thanks - very helpful as I've not been able to get my head around xpath yet! I've updated my question with my latest code & errors. If I lose the try/except then it goes through & does everything fine, but thats not ideal. Its an odd error I get though with the try - not sure if you can make any sense of it.

Comment: Your error might be because of the `browser.quit`. When the it goes to take the screenshot, the browser is closed. Try removing that line (was a bad choice by me to copy that from the selenium webdriver example). Also the index incrementation should be outside the try/except block (not sure if it's just a formatting error in the question or not).

Comment: Yeah thats an error in my formatting (it was lined up in the editor). Removing the quit does stop the error, but it reports success and failure for each itteration & the divs don't open at all. From some other things I'm doing with clicks on these I don't know if its just a timing issue.

Comment: I don't suppose the page you are testing is public or you have a page with the same accordion control? It would useful to be able to test some different solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately its not, and the way it all works is way too complicated to create a demo that I could host. I'll figure it out eventually I'm sure. For now it at least does what I need it to. Thanks for your help :)